# Easy to setup, multi-threaded server for my Django Piston API

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I am writing an API that reads from MySQL and Solr (which can give latencies of 150ms) to provide formatted output. I will be hosting this on a VPS, and I need to choose a **web server** for this application. It will be used only within localhost (and local LAN in future).

I have these concerns:

1. Launches multiple worker threads to minimize bottlenecks with **consurrent requests** (Solr can take 150ms to return a request)
2. Can **easily respawn** when a component crashes and restarting is just a matter of *servd -restart*
3. deploying a new application is as simple as **copying a folder to the www directory** (or equivalent) so that new requests to this app will be served from then on.

I am not optimizing for performance for now, so I need something **easy to setup**. And is #3 not possible for a non-load balanced Django app?

Answer (score 0):

[Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) is very simple to deploy and manage. It has no built-in reloading capability but you could easily use an external utility such as [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to monitor a directory and reload gunicorn using `kill -HUP <pid>`.